# .htacess with redirection and url parameters

Tags: .htaccess

I have the follow redirect code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://domain.com.ar%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /users/$1.php [QSA]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.domain.com.ar
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com.ar/$1
```

I need to deal with unknow url parameters, just to keep them on redirect, but it is not working.

Example: from `https: //domain.com.ar/username/?anyparametername=anyparametervalue` to `https: //domain.com.ar/users/username/?anyparametername=anyparametervalue`

How to fix this code?

Thank you very much!

I tried above code with no success.

Answer (score 0):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com\.ar$
RewriteRule ^ https://domain.com.ar%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/users/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /users/$1.php [QSA,L]
```

Note the additional `QSA` flag in the actual redirection rule.